# Connecting to MySql in app.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, express, async-await

I am writing a new app, and one of the requirements is that I use the "straight" express boilerplate that include `bin/www` and an `app.js`.

I normally just merge the two of them for convenience.  Now that I can't, I am wondering...

How can I connect to a DB (which is an async operation) from `app.js`?

What follows is the full app.js. This does NOT work, because as soon as this line happens:

```
var connection = await mysql.createConnectionP({
```

The anonymous function returns an unresolved promise. So the assigned "app" is incomplete, since the code to set it effectively hasn't yet run.

What is the best practice to connect asynchronously to a database keeping the app.js/www duo?

I *could* connect to the database in `www`, but then I would need to somehow pass the DB value back to `app.js` -- is that essentially the only way?

```
var express = require('express')
var path = require('path')
var favicon = require('serve-favicon')
var logger = require('morgan')
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser')
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')
var promisify = require('util').promisify

var index = require('./routes/index')
var users = require('./routes/users')

var app = express()

var prpl = require('prpl-server')
var jsonreststores = require('jsonreststores')
var mysql = require('mysql')

mysql.createConnectionP = promisify(mysql.createConnection)
console.log("1")

;(async () => {
  var connection = await mysql.createConnectionP({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'ppp',
    database: 'sasit'
  })

  connection.connectP = promisify(connection.connect)
  connection.queryP = promisify(connection.query)
  connection.endP = promisify(connection.end)

  await connection.connectP()

  var res = await connection.queryP('SELECT 1 + 1 AS solution')
  console.log('The solution is: ', res[0].solution)

  await connection.end()

  // view engine setup
  app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'))
  app.set('view engine', 'jade')

  // uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
  // app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
  app.use(logger('dev'))
  app.use(bodyParser.json())
  app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }))
  app.use(cookieParser())
  // app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

  // app.use('/', index);
  // app.use('/users', users);

  app.get('/*', prpl.makeHandler('./public/build', {
    builds: [
      {name: 'es6-unbundled', browserCapabilities: ['es2015', 'push']},
      {name: 'es6-bundled', browserCapabilities: ['es2015']},
      {name: 'es5-bundled'}
    ]
  }))

  // catch 404 and forward to error handler
  app.use(function (req, res, next) {
    var err = new Error('Not Found')
    err.status = 404
    next(err)
  })

  // error handler
  app.use(function (err, req, res, next) {
    // set locals, only providing error in development
    res.locals.message = err.message
    res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {}

    // render the error page
    res.status(err.status || 500)
    res.render('error')
  })
})()
module.exports = app
```

Comment: As far as I know, immediately calling an async function doesn't make it block.

Comment: Ok, it doesn't. So... where do people *actually* add their DB connection in the standard express boilerplate?!?

Comment: I've found using [Sequelize](http://sequelizejs.com) makes this a lot more straightforward since it wraps all the ugly internals of the driver in a nice, consistent outer layer. It also works with other databases so your code is more portable.